# Trim first 10 characters off the title of RSS feed

Tags: rss, xslt

I'm trying to write some xsl to style an RSS feed. I need to trim the first 10 characters off the title of each item.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?> 
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:template match="/rss">
<ul>
<xsl:for-each select="channel/item">
<li><strong><xsl:value-of select="title"/>
</strong>
<a href="{link}">More</a></li>
</xsl:for-each>
</ul>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="trimtitle">
<xsl:param name="string" select="." />
<xsl:if test="$string">
<xsl:text>Foo</xsl:text>
<xsl:call-template name="trimtitle">
<xsl:with-param name="string" select="substring($string, 10)" />
</xsl:call-template>
</xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="title">
<xsl:call-template name="title" />
<xsl:value-of select="." />
</xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: You have forgotten to provide a source XML document (short, please).

Answer (score 1):

I think you should write your substring function as this:

substring($string,1, 10)

Look at here

http://www.zvon.org/xxl/XSLTreference/Output/function_substring.html

Answer (score 1):

What are you doing in your trimtitle template?
Why are you calling trimtitle recursive..?

The easiest way to show a trimmed string is with:

```
<xsl:value-of select="substring(title,0,10)"/>
```

Comment: Thanks - that was just what I needed to uncomplicate the mess I was trying.  I appreciate it.